# Container cli is not running,when using couchdb hyperledger fabric

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I want to use chaincode-docker-devmode in fabric-samples to test my chaincode, but when I add couchdb in docker-compose-simple.yaml like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  orderer:
    container_name: orderer
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=orderer
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=orderer.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=DEFAULT
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp
      - GRPC_TRACE=all=true,
      - GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ./msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp
      - ./orderer.block:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/orderer.block
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984    



  peer:
    container_name: peer
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    dns_search: .
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DEFAULT
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=

    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    depends_on:
      - orderer
      - couchdb


  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DEFAULT
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/chaincodedev
    command: /bin/bash -c './script.sh ; sleep 20'
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp
        - ./../chaincode:/opt/gopath/src/chaincodedev/chaincode
        - ./:/opt/gopath/src/chaincodedev/
    depends_on:
      - orderer
      - peer

  chaincode:
    container_name: chaincode
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ccenv
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=example02
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DEFAULT
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/chaincode
    command: /bin/bash -c 'sleep 6000000'
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp
        - ./../chaincode:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode
    depends_on:
      - orderer
      - peer
```

When I start the containers, using

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-simple.yaml up
```

Container cil  will return the error:

```
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.29.0.4:7051: connect: connection refused"
```

some same errors are solve by add command:sleep in script,

```
command: /bin/bash -c 'sleep 6000000'
```

but my Container still return same error.

peer container's logs

```
2020-04-13 09:01:28.850 UTC [inproccontroller] getInstance -> DEBU 0f5 chaincode instance created for qscc-1.4.1

2020-04-13 09:01:28.850 UTC [inproccontroller] func2 -> DEBU 0f6 chaincode-support started for qscc-1.4.1

2020-04-13 09:01:28.850 UTC [inproccontroller] func1 -> DEBU 0f7 chaincode started for qscc-1.4.1

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 0f8 [] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: REGISTER in state created

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] HandleRegister -> DEBU 0f9 Received REGISTER in state created

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] Register -> DEBU 0fa registered handler complete for chaincode qscc:1.4.1

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] HandleRegister -> DEBU 0fb Got REGISTER for chaincodeID = name:"qscc:1.4.1" , sending back REGISTERED

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] HandleRegister -> DEBU 0fc Changed state to established for name:"qscc:1.4.1"

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] sendReady -> DEBU 0fd sending READY for chaincode name:"qscc:1.4.1"

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] sendReady -> DEBU 0fe Changed to state ready for chaincode name:"qscc:1.4.1"

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 0ff launch complete

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 100 Entry

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 101 Init QSCC

2020-04-13 09:01:28.851 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 102 [91196774] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready

2020-04-13 09:01:28.852 UTC [chaincode] Notify -> DEBU 103 [91196774] notifying Txid:91196774-4c1f-4369-b977-965de44d3d1b, channelID:

2020-04-13 09:01:28.852 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 104 Exit

2020-04-13 09:01:28.852 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 105 system chaincode qscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) deployed

2020-04-13 09:01:28.852 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 106 system chaincode (+lifecycle,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lifecycle) disabled

2020-04-13 09:01:28.852 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 107 Deployed system chaincodes

2020-04-13 09:01:28.855 UTC [ccprovider] ListInstalledChaincodes -> DEBU 108 Returning []

2020-04-13 09:01:28.850 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 109 container lock deleted(qscc-1.4.1)

2020-04-13 09:01:28.870 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 10a waiting for container(qscc-1.4.1) lock

2020-04-13 09:01:28.870 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 10b got container (qscc-1.4.1) lock

2020-04-13 09:01:28.870 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 10c container lock deleted(qscc-1.4.1)

2020-04-13 09:01:28.880 UTC [discovery] NewService -> INFO 10d Created with config TLS: false, authCacheMaxSize: 1000, authCachePurgeRatio: 0.750000

2020-04-13 09:01:28.880 UTC [nodeCmd] registerDiscoveryService -> INFO 10e Discovery service activated

2020-04-13 09:01:28.881 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 10f Starting peer with ID=[name:"peer" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer:7051]

2020-04-13 09:01:28.882 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 110 Started peer with ID=[name:"peer" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer:7051]

2020-04-13 09:01:32.819 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 111 Obtaining default signing identity

2020-04-13 09:01:32.819 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 112 Sign: plaintext: 18012A86070A2D0A09706565723A3730...455254494649434154452D2D2D2D2D0A

2020-04-13 09:01:32.819 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 113 Sign: digest: E3138D4C867225B5BEF15EC07062AABC2AF920CCEF7ED0545D3BB223B79F06FF

2020-04-13 09:01:32.820 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 114 Obtaining default signing identity

2020-04-13 09:01:32.821 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 115 Sign: plaintext: 0A09706565723A37303531

2020-04-13 09:01:32.821 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 116 Sign: digest: D18B553283AFC791A71A1AB3F379E85F4599DAAE3CE5B43F6A912E5BFD23E73D

2020-04-13 09:01:33.779 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 117 Obtaining default signing identity

2020-04-13 09:01:33.779 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 118 Sign: plaintext: 18012A86070A2D0A09706565723A3730...455254494649434154452D2D2D2D2D0A

2020-04-13 09:01:33.780 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 119 Sign: digest: EA29BD51F7F58B547912B79712CC7AE73D9CBFA0FF80817409EA7BFB1F95BF5B

2020-04-13 09:01:33.780 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 11a Obtaining default signing identity

2020-04-13 09:01:33.780 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 11b Sign: plaintext: 0A09706565723A37303531

2020-04-13 09:01:33.781 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 11c Sign: digest: D18B553283AFC791A71A1AB3F379E85F4599DAAE3CE5B43F6A912E5BFD23E73D

2020-04-13 09:01:33.782 UTC [gossip.discovery] periodicalSendAlive -> DEBU 11d Sleeping 5s
```

It's part of peer container's logs, it's still running and no error in it.

Is any one have any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: I think your peer container is also failing. Can you please paste the logs for `peer` container and update your question. That would help!

Comment: I add peer container s' logs in my question, but my peer container is running.